# How to check if a collection has changed?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I've created a JSON API with Express.js, Mongoose and MongoDB. Currently, there's no way for the clients of the API to check if the data in a collection has changed - they would need to download the whole collection periodically.

How could I allow the clients of the API to check for changes to a collections (inserts, updates, deletions) without downloading the collection itself?

Is there a way of getting the version number of the collection, the last change timestamp or a hash of the collection with Mongoose? What is the best practice solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6):

In current and earlier versions of MongoDB, you have to do it on the application side, maybe using polling.

MongoDB 3.6 has a brand new feature called [change stream](https://www.kenwalger.com/blog/nosql/mongodb/change-streams-coming-soon-mongodb-3-6/) that allows you to listen changes happening on your collections in real time.

The sample code to listen selected changes happening on your collection is below:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, assert = require('assert');
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://172.16.0.110:27017/myproject?readConcern=majority").then(function(client){
  var db = client.db('myproject')
  var changeStreams =  db.collection('documents').watch()
  changeStreams.on('change', function(change){
    console.log(change)  
  })

})
```

If you are using node.js, you need to use following node module to get it working:

```
"dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "mongodb/node-mongodb-native#3.0.0"
  }
```